# Do you release an official Token on Ropsten Test Network or the Ethereum Main Network?

Tags: solidity, remix, ropsten, etherscan

So I know this question might be really obvious but I seriously cannot find a single answer anywhere else. Let's say I finished making my token using Solidity in Remix and I want to put it out on the Ethereum network so that people can actually buy and sell my tokens. How do I go about this? Yes, I know that you have to go to wallet.ethereum.org and create a custom token, etc. But, do I create that custom token on a Ropsten Test Network or the Main Ethereum Network?

Or am I completely wrong and is there another "official" way of releasing a token that I made onto the network.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use the Main Ethereum Network.

If you were to deploy it to the Ropsten testnet, people could still purchase your token but they would be using 'fake' ether that can be obtained for free and thus your token would not have any real value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: your point about the "fake ether" was what I wasn't taking into consideration when thinking about this

Comment: I wasn't making a point but rather a distinction since _ether that can be obtained for free_ is a bad way to word it. But if I am understanding the question more clearly then I would say you might want to consider a crowdsale contract for the sale but for buying and selling you would need an exchange mechanism to enable liquidity. Regardless of which network even though the contracts themselves would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you deploy to a testnet to make sure things are good, and then deploy to the mainnet once you’re confident that your smart contract is bug free and ready for production use.